# Is it possible to read incoming data stream, using java, from Server to .exe client (Coded using C++)?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, client

Is it possible to read datastream sent from C++ server program to C++ client over socket connection in java? I have details like port number and server IP.

Or do I  need decompile the whole C++ client into Assembly and then somehow translate it into java to do that?

I'm really not sure what kind of data it's transforming, though.. Somebody told me to code HTTP server and run it on my Router but I'm not really sure if that would work?

Here’s the diagrammatic way to look at it.

```
Server generates data.
it puts it in a packet.
it encrypts the packet.
and sends it over the wire.
It gets to a user’s Computer (= client). (I should be in the control now on..)
(If I could somehow read data at this part?)
The client reads the encrypted packet.
(If I could somehow read data at this part?) (The later, the better :D)
The client decrypts the packet.
(If I could somehow read data at this part?) (The later, the better :D)
The client does something.
```

As said, the client is .exe file and it's coded using C++. And I don't have source code of it.

Comment: no need. all you need to know is data format that you will be receiving from your C++ server.

Comment: @Adi is there anyway to read the datastream without knowing the format? or is there anyway to find out the format?

Comment: you can read binary data from datastream but not sure what is benefit of it if you don't know what to do with that binary data.

Comment: @Adi So I'm kind of making 3rd party program, since the client is also in C++.. :D Sorry for my bad explanation.. I also edited the original question. Described it a little more..

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is define well your application protocol. This is, the format of your data stream. As long as you are using the same format in both ends, it doesn't really matter what language or program you are using. Imagine your browser and the web server. They are both using the same application protocol (HTTP) but they are completely different programs. Even more, there exists different web servers and different browsers.

Then, all you need to do is use the java sockets to listen to some specific port, and use your c++ sockets to write to the specific port. Just make sure you know how the information is "organized".

Comment: So I can read incoming data from ip and port and the client can still read the same data? And I think I can decrypt the data received once I just learn how to read it? It will probably take awhile to learn to read it, but after a while it will all make sense? :D

Comment: That's not really what I meant

Comment: Ok, first, you can always read (Monitor) the wire to any specific port and read whatever is on it. this is, even if you are not in the TCP session (assuming that you are using TCP) you can get the packages (like wireshark). Second, if you are not talking about application layer, I still don't understand your question.