# ServerSocket MySql connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, sockets

I have created a simple java serversocket that listens to port 3306(in myEclipse). Then I try to connect to MySQL using toad. When I connect, the code reaches the break point that I have placed in the serversocket class. I can extract the IP and port number using: `System.out.println(s.toString());//where s is the Socket.`

Brief code:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3306); Socket s = ss.accept();   
System.out.println(s.toString());//Socket[addr=/192.0.0.6,port=57915,localport=3306]
```

What I need is the remaining details that are sent while creating connection like username and password.

How can these be extracted?
The purpose is to monitor the queries and allow only specific ones to go through.

Thanks.

Comment: What you again?

Comment: hey @ScaryWombat  didn't get what you asking

Comment: Did you not again exactly the same question about an hour ago?  The question was asked exactly the same - coincidence?

Comment: yep this is an unofficial account...any solution to my weird requirement?

Comment: @ScaryWombat no flies on you today! FYI the other question appears to have been removed.

Comment: Hi @user3738243  
Saw ur post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670635/is-it-possible-to-read-incoming-data-stream-using-java-from-server-to-exe-cli   there is some relation between our post and mine, did you find any solution for the same?